# TFS - TF.exe /lock:none parameter doesn't have any effects

Tags: tfs

I try to add a file without locking it but `tf.exe` tries to lock it anyway. I don't know if this is a bug or something intentional. The command that I use is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\amd64>tf add C:\FilePath\myDll.dll /login:tfsbuild /lock:none
```

Throws error:

> TF10151: Cannot lock item
>   $/SourceControlPath/myDll.dll for
>   check-out.  The item
>   $/SourceControlPath/myDll.dll is checked
>   out by XUSER in workspace XWORKSPACEOFUSER.

This file doesn't exist in source control and the reason it is checked out by someone else is that this file was removed before and XUSER doesn't have the latest sources and still has that file and checked out in his workspace which is normal and I want to add it again with command prompt.

This problem breaks my TFS Builds and I didn't understand why `/lock:none` doesn't have any effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the server enforces locking, then your lock will *always* be upgraded by the server.

This is a server-side policy that your server administrator has enabled.  The only way around this policy is to disable it.

Comment: I thought it was disabled at first and didn't check that option but you were right. I allowed multiple checkouts for Executable Files(dll, exe etc.) and the problem went away. However what I didn't understand is this: our developers have a few batch files that do some xcopy work and overwrite these dlls and because of that xcopies; that dlls get checked out in their workspaces. They execute that batchs a lot and how would more than one developer did have checkout on these dlls if multiple checkout is not allowed? Because of this reason, I thought it was enabled and didn't check that out at 1st